# How do I install Linux drivers for my network card on a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have an X64 OS and I am running Linux on a virtual machine.
My question is, how do I install Linux drivers for my network card on the virtual machine?

Comment: Your VM needs the virtual drivers.  Not the drivers for the physical hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install network drivers (and other  drivers) on your Linux in a VirtualBox. Here are a few articles that you might want to read to get a hint of it and why you might want to do so (Google around and you will find tons of resources if you need specifics):

- [Resource 1](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-xen_sd_draft/cha.xen.driver.html)
- [Resource 2](https://www.suse.com/products/vmdriverpack/)
- [Resource 3](http://www.ehow.com/how_6240161_install-drivers-virtual-pc.html)

Comment: Yes, you can install network drivers (and other drivers) on your linux in a virtual box. Here area few articles that you might want to read to get a hint of it and why you might want to do so Thanks, that was very helpful

Comment: sarcasm? I did mention few examples